# simple markup for jinja2 or html textarea

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, markup, jinja2

I am writing a google app engine web app using python and jinja2.  Is there a simple lightweight textarea markup that I can use either for jinja2 or just generally for an HTML text area.  I just want line breaks to come across and italics and bold and maybe one or two other things but I don't just want to mark is safe (and not autoescape the rest of it).

I am surprised that no one has asked a similar question and they probably have so maybe I'm just using the wrong keywords.

Comment: What would you expect an answer to this question to look like? I'm not really sure what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) to add markup features to a textarea. Visitors of your site (or administrators, if that's where you happen to use it) can then add HTML markup in a user-friendly way.

Alternatively, you could add a [Markdown parser](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) (or a similar language) that allows users to add markup using basic symbols. Your website would parse and process the content prior to displaying it.

Comment: ah I had looked at that but not in-depth enough to realize that you can  take off some of the options.  great at its most basic that's just what i wanted.  thanks!